# HuggingFace Dataset with 4 custom splits?

Tags: huggingface-datasets

I have 4 JSON containing the same structure and the same amount of data (but the contents are different). I upload 4 files to my HuggingFace dataset repository.

**My first try**

Uploaded 4 files to repository directory:

- data-1.json
- data-2.json
- data-3.json
- data-4.json

As a result, HuggingFace combined 4 files into 1 dataset.

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 551964
    })
})
```

**My second try**

I renamed the 4 files into `alpha.json`, `beta.json`, `delta.json`, `gamma.json`. The result is the same.

**My third try**

I put the 4 files into 4 folders:

- alpha/data-1.json
- beta/data-2.json
- delta/data-3.json
- gamma/data-4.json

The result is still the same.

According to this [official documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/repository_structure), it only recognizes certain file & folder patterns.

My goal is to load my dataset like this, with 4 custom splits:

```
ds = load_dataset("myusername/my-dataset")
print(ds)
```

and the output is:

```
DatasetDict({
    alpha: Dataset({ # loads data-1.json
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 137991
    }),
    beta: Dataset({ # loads data-2.json
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 137991
    }),
    delta: Dataset({ # loads data-3.json
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 137991
    }),
    gamma: Dataset({ # loads data-4.json
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 137991
    })
})
```

The only stupid way I can think of is to create 4 dataset repositories, which is uneasy to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that I need a special folder and file naming pattern to achieve my goal:

```
my_repository/
├── README.md
└── data/
    ├── alpha-00000-of-00001.csv
    ├── beta-00000-of-00001.csv
    ├── delta-00000-of-00001.csv
    ├── gamma-00000-of-00001.csv
```

which the `load_dataset()` function will result:

```
DatasetDict({
    alpha: Dataset({
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 137991
    })
    beta: Dataset({
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 137991
    })
    delta: Dataset({
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 137991
    })
    gamma: Dataset({
        features: ['translation'],
        num_rows: 137991
    })
})
```

Comment: huggingface library is a mess - was this even documented? It's extremely useful.